# Extract string value of an ENUM in a Typescript Object

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an Enum:

```
export enum DistanceMeasure {
Miles, Kilometers
```

}

To use in a user object:

```
export class User {
... some stuff
MaxTravelDistance:  number;
DistanceMeasure:    DistanceMeasure;
MaxTravelTime:      TimeSpan;
... some more stuff
```

}

So the info comes from the server as 0 (zero) or 1 for the DistanceMeasure and thats fine. 
But I need to present the string e.g. "Miles".

In my (Angular/Ionic) app, the output of

```
      console.log(user.DistanceMeasure);
```

is '0' (zero).
However I read that to extract the enum string you should use it as an index.
If I do:

```
      console.log(user.DistanceMeasure[0]);
```

It comes back as undefined.

Why is that? since the user.DistanceMeasure is of type DistanceMeasure?
Is it no longer an enum ?
Thanks.

Comment: Your variable names should start with lowercase!

Comment: `DistanceMeasure[0]` should output `Miles`. `user.DistanceMeasure` is not an array nor an object . it's a property of the `User` class and it's value can be something defined in the `DistanceMeasure` enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `DistanceMeasure[user.DistanceMeasure]`, as in the following snippet:

```
enum DistanceMeasure {
    Miles, Kilometers
}

class User {
    DistanceMeasure:　DistanceMeasure;
}

const user = new User();
user.DistanceMeasure = 0;

console.log(DistanceMeasure[user.DistanceMeasure]); // Miles
```

What's contributing greatly to the confusion is that fact that you're not following naming conventions, and thus end up with properties that have the same name as your enum.

Comment: Yes, I had reached that conclusion myself shortly after, however the edit to my question seems to have become lost. Trying to keep the same names as used on the server. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, enums have numeric value as 0,1,2...
You can define your enum like:

```
export enum DistanceMeasure {
    Miles = 'Miles',
    Kilometers = 'Kilometers'
}
```

And now `DistanceMeasure.Miles` will have value as 'Miles'.

Comment: He needs the numeric values. He just needs to display the key title

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at String Enum in the [Typscript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

```
enum Direction {
    Up = "UP",
    Down = "DOWN",
    Left = "LEFT",
    Right = "RIGHT",
}
```

And i suggest to look into [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime) so u understand how they work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define custom values enum has integer values starting from 0 in the order they are declared.
If you want them to have string values you have to declare them like

```
enum DistanceMeasure {
    Miles = 'MILES',
    Kilometers = 'KILOMETERS'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and unlike regular enums they are completely removed during compilation. Const enum members are inlined at use sites. This is possible since const enums cannot have computed members.

So, from your `enum` you can create a new variable `distanceMeasure` to use it like as an array:

```
export enum DistanceMeasure {
  Miles, Kilometers
}

const distanceMeasure = [DistanceMeasure.Miles, DistanceMeasure.Kilometers];

console.log(distanceMeasure[0]); // --> Miles
```

Read more about **TypeScript Enums** at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not explicity defined the values for your enums so they have got default values of 0 and 1. Now you are getting 0 and 1 from server, so that maps correctly to the enum. What you do is to write a pipe to format 0 as "Mile" and 1 as "Kilometer".

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'unit'
})
export class UnitPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() {
  }
  transform(value: DistanceMeasure ): any {
    return value === DistanceMeasure.Mile ? 'Mile' : 'Kilometer'
  }

}
```

And in your html use it like this

```
{{ user.DistanceMeasure | unit }}
```